# Display text but NOT if either $variable1 OR $variable2 are TRUE

Tags: php, if-statement

I have one of those problems that should be quite simple, but has got me stumped.

I have a limitless number of variables: $variable1, $variable2, $variable3, $variable4, etc

I have a bunch of HTML that I want to display, but NOT if either $variable1 or $variable2 is true.

I started off with this, but it doesn't work...

```
//Display the following, but NOT if $variable1 OR $variable2 are TRUE
if ( !$variable1 || !$variable2 ){
```

Comment: *"Limitless number"* .. that sounds terrible.

Comment: There are all these limitless variables come from?

Comment: It's not really limitless. The variables are added manually, so we're only talking 5-10 variables.

Comment: You're talking about mutual exclusive, i.e. `XOR`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These statements will return true if neither is true (as stated in the title):

```
!($variable1 || $variable2)
// or
!$variable1 && !$variable2`
```

These are equivalent according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

---

This referred to an [outdated version of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17217838/1):

<strike>This statement will return true if exactly one of both variables is true (as stated in the 3rd paragraph):</strike>

```
$variable1 XOR $variable2
// or 
($variable1 && !$variable2) || ($variable2 && !$variable1)
```

---

As you stated you have a limitless amount of variables you should consider using an array and checking the values in a `foreach`-loop.

Comment: Thanks @TimWolla. And yes I was being very stupid! This is what I used:
`if (!$variable1  && !$variable2 ){`

Comment: I like the series of edits as you notice the inconsistency between the title, the body, and the supposedly dysfunctional code :)

Comment: @MarkR21 Please edit the question to match the title or edit the title to match the question

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too.

```
if($variable1 xor $variable2)
```